# Signature for this request is not valid

Tags: exchanges, api, javascript

im testing the binance api but cant get over the signature problem can u spot a mistake on my signature?:

```
   const crypted = CryptoJs.HmacSHA256("timestamp=" + new Date().getTime().toString() + "&recvWindow=5000" , this.APISECRET).toString();
```

Comment: Probable duplicate of  [Binance API SIGNED GET request error code -1100 on signature parameter](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/67365/binance-api-signed-get-request-error-code-1100-on-signature-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

I am just taking a wild guess, your signature needs to be encoded correctly. You can see some examples in this [ask](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/67365/binance-api-signed-get-request-error-code-1100-on-signature-parameter?rq=1).